# How can I change default values from Locale (flutter_localizations)?

Tags: flutter

In my app I'am using the `flutter_localizations` package to translate the `DatePicker`s to Spanish.

It works well when I show the calendar, but there is a problem with the `TimePicker`.

I want to display the `TimePicker` in 12 hours format.

But the `TimePicker` is allways 24 hours when the `Locale` is `Locale('es')` and there is not a method to set the `TimePicker` 12 hours manually (There is a method but only to set 24 hours manually).

The TimePicker class grab the `TimeOfDayFormat` from the `Locale` values and with that makes all the adjustments to display the `TimePicker` in 12 hour format or 24.

```
final TimeOfDayFormat timeOfDayFormat = MaterialLocalizations.of(context)
    .timeOfDayFormat(alwaysUse24HourFormat: media.alwaysUse24HourFormat);
```

The value of `timeOfDayFormat` when the `Locale` is `Locale('es')` is:

```
TimeOfDayFormat.H_colon_mm
```

And when the `Locale` is `Locale('en')` is:

```
TimeOfDayFormat.h_colon_mm_space_a
```

**So. How can I change the default value of `timeOfDayFormat` in the`Locale("es")`?**